# Time series - Differencing vs Dividing

Tags: time-series, forecasting

What is the difference between using differencing or dividing to treat trends / seasonality ?
Most approaches seem to be using differencing. Is there a qualitative preference for why we do this ?

For instance given a time series ts

Would ts/ts.shift(7) be qualitative different from ts-ts.shift(7) ? How do we assess which method is better ?

Answer (score 1):

The ts/ts.shift(7) can be represented as log(ts) - log(ts.shift(7)) if we take logarithm. So, the difference is if we want to look at the times series on the log scale or on the original scale.